# Error block of angularJs is not being executed

Tags: javascript, json, spring, angularjs

I am using angularJS and spring 3.2.4 for REST exception handling and handling exception like this

```
 @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
     @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
     @ResponseBody
     public ErrorFormInfo handleMethodArgumentNotValid(HttpServletRequest req, MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {

             String errorMessage = "gender sring is out of range";
             String errorURL = req.getRequestURL().toString();
             System.out.println("Throwing exception from exception handler");
             ErrorFormInfo errorInfo = new ErrorFormInfo(errorURL, errorMessage);
             return errorInfo;
     }
```

whenever sent argument validation fails it throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException and correct me if i am wrong that spring 3.2 converts the objects in json format automatically
but i am not able to get the object in error block of angularJs. It throws the error saying "Response is undefined" with this output

```
completeRequest(callback=done(status, response, headersString), status=400, response="{"errorMessage":"http:/...sring is out of range"}", headersString="Server: Apache-Coyote/1...MT\r\nConnection: close\r\n")angular-1.0.7.js (line 9333)
onreadystatechange()
```

I suspect that object is not being converted into JSON because is has strange header string.

Below is my JS code

```
 $http.post('rest/create?cd=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
                            XYZ
                    .success(function(data) {
    alert('Data added successfully');                                               
                            }).error(function(data) {   
                                var errorInfo = data;
                                alert("data from server side"+errorInfo.errorMessage);
                        alert("Unable to process");
                    });
```

Please help...Thanks in advance

Comment: i  can`t  see  any   question...may  be you want  error block of angularjs  to be execute ?

Comment: yes saurabh..This is what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an interceptor injected in **$httpProvider** service of angularJs which run only for success and error. so I wrote a the piece of code in promise to handle response 'undefined'
case. Code is as follows:

```
 if(jsonStr.ERROR_URI != 'undefined')
      {
            var jsonStr = response.data;    
            console.log('inside error block');  
            console.log('response.status'+response.status); 
            console.log('response.data'+response.data); 
            console.log('response.data.ERROR_URI'+jsonStr.ERROR_URI);
            return $q.reject(response);
      }
```

it simply rejects the response if it is undefined. It solved my problem.